# Crystal Report Formula IF Then Else Remove Decimals

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to remove 2 digit decimals in Crystal Report formula using if then else.
The way that I have tried does not help me to solve myproblem. How do I fix it ?
Here is my code;

```
if ({purchaseorder.CUR} = "IDR")
then Truncate({purchaseorder.UPRI})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your number field, select Format Field, Number Tab, Customize...

Set the following expression for the Decimals property:

```
if ({purchaseorder.CUR} = "IDR") then 0 ELSE 2
```

Comment: It works, I am sorry I did not relize it that the code it was so simple. Thank you for your kind information